# Prompting user to install Flash player if not installed already?

Tags: flash, internet-explorer

When a user visits your flash-rich webpage from Internet Explorer, and he/she doesn't have Adobe Flash Player Active X installed, how do you automatically prompt the user to install it by automatically opening the active x web installer file?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the industry standard [swfObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) for embedding flash movies, you will be able to get the user to download flash without leaving your site seamlessly.